# How to minimize sum of reciprocals under multiple linear constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Given $A\in(\mathbb{R}_{>0})^{n\times m}$, $b\in(\mathbb{R}_{>0})^{m} $ and $c\in(\mathbb{R}_{>0})^{n}$,

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in (\Bbb R_{>0})^n}{\text{minimize}} & f(x) := \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{c_i}{x_i} \\ \text{subject to} & Ax \leq b\end{array} $$

where $\leq$ denotes component-wise inequality.

I am stuck with this optimization problem in my projects. Currently, I am trying to solve the problem with numerical methods (e.g., [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) on Matlab). I want to know whether an analytical solution exists or how to relax this problem to be convex.

Comment: Isn't this a [geometric program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_programming)?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is convex, as demonstrated by the following second-order cone formulation, obtained by introducing $y_i$ to represent $1/x_i$:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_i c_i y_i \\
&\text{subject to} & A x &\le b \\
&& z &= \sqrt 2 \\
&& 2 x_i y_i &\ge z^2 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1\\
&& x_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
&& y_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} is a rotated second-order cone constraint.  Everything else is linear.